# syntax error even after checking code thrice in python

Tags: python, syntax, ide, sublimetext3

I am getting some syntax error in sublime text and red highlight on elif command in my text.

i am a beginner in coding so their may be some problem that i can't notice.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLrWX.png)
`pylint: error E0001 - invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 49) (syntax-error)`

```
print("-------------Welcome User-------------")
choice = 0

while TRUE:

    print("1.Square.")
    print("2.Rectangle.")
    print("3.Circle.")
    
    choice = int(input("Enter your choice : "))

    if choice == 1:
        print("1.Area.")
        print("2.Perimeter.")
        ch = int(input("Enter your choice : "))
        if ch == 1:
            l = float(input("Enter the length : "))
            area = l * l
            print("The area is : ",area)
        elif ch == 2:
            l = float(input("Enter the length : "))
            per = 4 * l
            print("The perimeter is : ",per)
        else:
            print("Wrong choice\n")
            i = input()
    elif choice == 2:
        print("1.Area")
        print("2.Perimeter.")
        ch = int(input("Enter your choice : "))
        if ch == 1:
            l = float(input("Enter the length : "))
            b = float(input("Enter the breadth : "))
            area = l * b
            print("The area is : ",area)
        elif ch == 2:
            l = float(input("Enter the length : "))
            b = float(input("Enter the breadth : "))
            per = 2*(l + b)
            print("The perimeter is : ",per)
        else:
            print("Wrong Choice\n")
            i = input()
    elif choice == 3:
        print("1.Area")
        print("2.Circumference")
        ch = int(input("Enter your choice : ")
        if ch == 1:
            r = float(input("Enter the radius : "))
            print("The area is : ",r*r*3.14)
        elif ch == 2:
            r = float(input("Enter the radius : "))
            print("The perimeter is : ",2*3.14*r)
    else:
        print("Wrong choice.")
        i = input()
```

Comment: Are you getting python SyntaxErrors or are you using a linter and getting lint errors? And which line is 49?

Comment: At a guess, put `r*r*3.14` in brackets

Comment: in `choice==3` you are missing a closing parenthesis on `ch = int(input("Enter your choice : ")` should be `ch = int(input("Enter your choice : "))`

Comment: In general, when you have a syntax error in python, look to the line above the line it calls out as syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

In the `elif choice == 3` block, you have this line:

```
ch = int(input("Enter your choice : ")
```

That line causes the error, because you're missing the closing parentheses on the end.